# Sample size determination for before/after study

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, paired-data, mcnemar-test

I would like to estimate the required sample size for a study where I have subjects first undergo an observation (control) period of X months and then an intervention period of Y months. The outcome is a rate (# of events per time at risk). So I would have a rate for period X and a rate for period Y for all subjects, i.e. it should be a paired test.

Any one have any ideas what is the best test for sample size determination?

Comment: best in terms of what? sample precision?

Comment: Good question. I meant most appropriate. I have been looking at McNemar's test, but this seems to be for paired probabilities, not rates... In my case, subjects can experience multiple events in periods X and/or Y.

Comment: I think you are doing this backwards. Do you not need to pick your analysis method first so as to estimate an adequate sample size?

Comment: yes this is indeed my question. I want to determine the most appropriate analysis method to determine my sample size for such a study, making assumptions about e.g. the intervention effect